# Do I have to call super.componentDidUpdate in React?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

In a subclass of `React.Component`, do I have to call `super.componentDidUpdate` from my `componentDidUpdate` method? Or is it done automatically?

(I am trying to call it but there is an error message *Cannot read property `call` of `undefined`*)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not, as you can see in the base class that you are extending, [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/4f73ce2c95284f38dff028c25619fcd9a4797b67/src/isomorphic/modern/class/ReactComponent.js), it has no `componentDidUpdate`, so calling a super method doesn't make sense.

Instead of always having the method be present, and sometimes have it do nothing, React instead checks if the method exists. That can be see [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/2b53acb00ad8bbb6ecd83d000385a948e095401b/src/renderers/shared/reconciler/ReactCompositeComponent.js#L677).

Answer (score 1):

The base `React.Component` doesn't have a `componentDidUpdate` method.  It just has hooks where it calls `componentDidUpdate` if the component has that method.

So, the error message that you are seeing means you tried to call a function named `call` of the object `undefined`.  Cannot read property *call* of *undefined*

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve.

I assume you extended React.Component with ES6 syntax thats why you saying its a `subclass`. If that's the case, you probably don't need/have to call `super.componentDidUpdate` at all